# jQuery errors after moving site

Tags: 7, javascript, migrations

I've created a website in a dev-environment with a generic domain name and have recently moved the site to the production environment by just copying over the `public_html` folder.

Everything works except `JuiceBox` and the `Plupload integration` module don't show on the website (it's just blank). All I get are the errors below:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at js_xeOt4HeIpEI0bFGorNg4JgdnWBSWP0hr-DA_a_DRSzo.js:4
Uncaught ReferenceError: Drupal is not defined
    at js_BLxotNs2yt7YGlf9QRI9L9AMfdnkQfnN-_ADBTW3SiE.js:116
    at js_BLxotNs2yt7YGlf9QRI9L9AMfdnkQfnN-_ADBTW3SiE.js:778
Uncaught ReferenceError: Drupal is not defined
    at js_nd8T7IjV_42lQdGnEwc3XNCech9Hjagy-6Y7Hoou9Eo.js:1
Uncaught Error: Bootstraps JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4
    at js_uqRgtjNVU0Yel0hoh587qzn-ybcZ5logPIpmByaAZ-Y.js:15
    at js_uqRgtjNVU0Yel0hoh587qzn-ybcZ5logPIpmByaAZ-Y.js:17
Uncaught ReferenceError: Drupal is not defined
    at js_v89jUZ_l2LR8NzEXW2kWQ6me12tC-jCbLw8O3mpuQ2A.js:7
    at js_v89jUZ_l2LR8NzEXW2kWQ6me12tC-jCbLw8O3mpuQ2A.js:12
Uncaught ReferenceError: Drupal is not defined
    at blog:34
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'bootstrap' of undefined
    at js_OTdL_00eEtQq3wzsUAHLDYwgtcHpzbgUFYeJRcQf8f8.js:13
    at js_OTdL_00eEtQq3wzsUAHLDYwgtcHpzbgUFYeJRcQf8f8.js:272
```

The files referenced seem to me that they come with the modules. Therefore I have reinstalled and configured the necessary modules, but the errors won't go away.

The only difference I see between my dev and production is that I HTTPS in production.

What can cause these errors? And how can I fix them?

Thanks for having a look

Comment: Have you cleared cache? Are these files missing?

Comment: Yes the cache has been cleared and the files reside in the "/sites/all/default/files/js"-folder